# ASP Cannot read configuration file in vmware shared folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis-express

I have problem in my development machine. I've put the development inside vmware with all my project files in the vmware shared folder but when I try to run my asp mvc project, it results in the error:

> "Cannot read configuration file" and "Config file:
>   \?\Z:\Work\Shared\Dev2\workspace\projects\Test\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\web.config".

I've read many blogs that recommend changing the file permission, but nothing works. Can anyone help?

I use Windows 7, Visual Studio 2013 and IIS express to run the project.

Thanks in advance,
Reynaldi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grant IIS Express permission to access network drive in VMWare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28493315/grant-iis-express-permission-to-access-network-drive-in-vmware)