# Grant IIS Express permission to access network drive in VMWare

Tags: asp.net, vmware, file-permissions, iis-express, network-drive

I have a Windows 7 virtual machine in VMWare that I'm using to develop ASP.NET MVC 5 Web applications with the default IIS Express server. I like to keep my projects saved on an external hard drive which I can access in the virtual machine through a shared folder / network drive. However, when I run my applications, IIS Express cannot access my web.config files in the project directory. It's looking in the right folder so I'm pretty sure this is a permissions issue. How can I grant IIS Express file access to the files on my network drive?

**Things I've tried**

- Running Visual Studio as an administrator
- Setting iisexpress.exe to always run as an administrator
- Looking around in the applicationhost.config file
- Attempting to set write permissions on the network drive (right click on the drive and go to properties but no "Security" tab available)
- A few other things that I can't remember that I tried during the hours of searching for a solution

**Known last resorts that I'd prefer to avoid**

- Copying the project files from the external hard drive to the VM's storage space and vice versa
- Running the projects on a full IIS server

**Other things to know**

- Using Visual Studio 2013 and MVC 5
- Using IIS Express 7.5
- VMWare Workstation 11
- The virtual machine is also on the external hard drive, so I can't connect the usb to the guest, I need to access the rest of the hard drive through shared folders (although doubtful, maybe partitioning the hard drive would fix this?)
- Guest OS is Windows 7 Professional
- Host OS is Debian Jessie RC1
- External HDD is formatted as NTFS, although it shows up as HGFS on the network drive
- I can read and write to files on the network drive, it's just IIS Express that is having trouble

Comment: Programs don't have permissions, users do. If the user account that IIS Express is running under (usually your own) can access the files via explorer, then it's not a permissions issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VMware/VirtualBox's shared folder between the guest and host is kind of using mapped drive feature of Windows. However, neither IIS nor IIS Express supports mapped drives. If possible, use a sync tool, such as Dropbox, or simply Git to share bits between the two.

Comment: It looks like that's what it has come down to. Thanks for the answer

Comment: A peer-to-peer sync tool such as [Resilio Sync](https://www.resilio.com/individuals/) should (in theory) be faster than DropBox.

Comment: Update: I've applied Resilio Sync to this problem and it's working marvellously! I'm now able to work, commit and push from a regular folder in MacOS and the changes are automatically synced to a folder on the VM, where they can be built with `MSBuild` and are served by IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue to this, and what I found was that when you specify your physical path in IIS as a mapped drive, e.g. `Z:\shared-folder` IIS fails with HTTP 500 error.

However is you specify the path like this: `\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\shared-folder` then suddenly it works and the app has all the permissions to write to files.

This works both in IIS and IISExpress.